# C++: Declaring `auto` function return type in prototype still leads to use of `auto` before deduction error

Tags: c++, prototype, auto

I wrote a function called `generate_random_matrix` with a return type of `auto` in the following code snippet. When I put the function before the `main` function, the code works fine. But when I put the function below the `main` function, and include a prototype at the top, the code gives me the usual error

```
 error: use of ‘auto generate_random_matrix(double, double) [with int rows = 10; int cols = 10]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
     auto test_matrix = generate_random_matrix<10,10>(0, 2);
```

Here is the actual code snippet that is not working. Any suggestions as to why this is not working?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

template <int rows, int cols>
auto generate_random_matrix(double lower_, double upper_);

int main()
{
    auto test_matrix = generate_random_matrix<10,10>(0, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << test_matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


template <int rows, int cols>
auto generate_random_matrix(double lower_, double upper_)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
    std::vector<double> inner_result;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        inner_result.erase(inner_result.begin(), inner_result.end());
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            inner_result.push_back(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(lower_, upper_)(gen));
        }
        result.push_back(inner_result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would the compiler know what the function returns, if it haven't seen the function definition (implementation) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned the `auto` cannot be deduced in `main()`, since the compile didn't see the return type from the forward declaration of the templated function.

Just move the whole definition before `main()` to get it working:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

template <int rows, int cols>
auto generate_random_matrix(double lower_, double upper_)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
    std::vector<double> inner_result;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        inner_result.erase(inner_result.begin(), inner_result.end());
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            inner_result.push_back(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(lower_, upper_)(gen));
        }
        result.push_back(inner_result);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto test_matrix = generate_random_matrix<10,10>(0, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << test_matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7836de22505e3db5)

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I had not seen this behavior before, but I can just move the code around. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @krishnab For production code you would move that function definition to a header file anyways.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I was using this for some test cases, but you are right about moving it to a header file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` is a hint to the compiler to deduce the type at compile-time. In your case it has to deduce return type by examining the code and thus it fails to deduce in the prototype because it does not see return (yet) of that method.